# Amazon Lex and Connect text formatting not working as intended, works fine with other platforms

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-lex, amazon-connect

Text formatting appears to work fine with any message that comes directly from a Lambda response but if it was written in the Lex designer it just doesn't look the same.

Here's how it looks:
[image: Left text written in the slot prompt. Right text I get from the lambda response]

Here's the lambda response just in case:

```json
{
        "sessionState": {
            "dialogAction": {
                "type": "ElicitSlot",
                "slotToElicit": "test_slot"
            },
            "intent": {
                "name": "test",
                "state": "InProgress"
            }
        },
        "messages": [
            {
                "contentType": "PlainText",
                "content": "test \ntest",
            }
        ]
    }
```

- I tried using custom payloads, realized that Connect doesn't support this.
- Tried using markdown, Lex can't handle it, plus it appears all the text in a message can only be written as a one line.
- Haven't tried doing everything from lambda because it requires a lot a rework and I have a deadline.
- I have been googling a lot but I don't know if I'm not using the right words because I can't seem to find anything relating to my specific problem, so I've been wasting a lot of time with this.

Answer (score 1):

The Lex console seems to escape control characters which is why `\n` appears for intents created/updated through the designer but is interpreted correctly for responses from Lambda hooks.

One thing you can try is calling the API directly; for example, if you call [DescribeIntent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lexv2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeIntent.html) for that intent you will see the escaped characters (`Puedes preguntar sobre los siguientes temas: \\n1`). You can then use [UpdateIntent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lexv2/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateIntent.html) to update the message with the correct, unescaped characters.

Comment: Thanks, it seems there is no simple way to solve this.